# how to combine window.location.href and DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript

I am using ipinfo.io to detect the visitors country and then reload the page with an appended querystring based on that. When the page loads I would like to do something  after DOMContentLoaded.

DOMContentLoaded is called fine if I don't reload the page, but I would like it to work with the reload. How do I achieve that?

Sample code below:

```
jQuery.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function(data){
    if(data){
        if(data.country){
            if(data.country.toLowerCase()=='us')
            {
                window.location.replace(window.location.href+"?location=us");
            }
        }
    }
});

//works when page is not reloaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
   function() {
    doSomething...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a race condition here: based on your description it is likely that the `getJSON` command is "racing" with the `DOMContentLoaded` event. If `getJSON` is successful before your DOM is ready, then it will redirect the page and stop all script execution on the page.

To avoid that, try moving `getJSON` into the `DOMContentLoaded` callback.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  jQuery.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
    if (data) {
      if (data.country) {
        if (data.country.toLowerCase() == 'us') {
          window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?location=us");
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Other logic here

});
```

On a side note, you can avoid triple nesting by combining the three `if` statements (and remember to use strict comparison whenever possible, `===`):

```js
jQuery.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
    if (data && data.country && data.country.toLowerCase() === 'us') {
        window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?location=us");
    }
}
```